# Origin of fag (meaning a cigarette in British English)

Tags: etymology, british-english

Aside from the offensive meaning, colloquial British English uses the term ***fag*** to indicate a cigarette.

> James has gone outside for a fag

In my googling, I thought perhaps this originates from one of the possible meanings of ***faggot***:

> a bundle of sticks, twigs, or branches bound together and used as fuel, a fascine, a torch, etc.
>
> [*dictionary.reference.com*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/faggot?s=t)

In a very loose sense, this definition could be applied to a cigarette. It's a collection of materials (tar, tobacco, etc) bound together for burning.

The origin from *[Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fag&searchmode=none)* indicates:

> 1888, probably from fag "loose piece, last remnant of cloth" (late 14c., as in fag-end "extreme end, loose piece," 1610s)

This appears to be speculative, and doesn't necessarily explain why this definition fell into common usage to indicate a cigarette. I'm looking for something more concrete indicating what caused it to be used in this context.

What is the origin of this meaning of the word?

Comment: I'll note that "fag" was a common term for "cigarette" among youth in the US back ca 1960.  The usage was likely snuffed out by the competing meaning of "homosexual".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=fag&allowed_in_frame=0), it comes from "fag", meaning a loose piece of cloth:

> fag (n.1) Look up fag at Dictionary.com
> British slang for "cigarette" (originally, especially, the butt of a smoked cigarette), 1888, probably from fag "loose piece, last remnant of cloth" (late 14c., as in fag-end "extreme end, loose piece," 1610s), which perhaps is related to fag (v.), which could make it a variant of flag (v.).

The OED is a bit more convinced and categorically links it to *fag-end*:

> Etymology: Abbreviation of fag-end. (Cf. fag sb.2 2.)
>
> **a**. The fag-end of a cigarette. **b**. A cheap cigarette. **c**. Any cigarette
> (the current use). Also attrib., as fag card, a cigarette card; fag
> hag (see quot. 1945).
>
> - 1888 Sat. Rev. 30 June 786/2 ― They··burn their throats with the
>   abominable ‘fag’, with its acrid paper and vile tobacco.
> - 1893 Pick-me-up 14 Oct. 45/2 ― Stimulants he calls ‘booze’ and a cigarette
>   a ‘fag’.
> - 1898 Eng. Dial. Dict. s.v., ― Here [sc. at Redruth] we are
>   often asked by youngsters to ‘chuck’ them ‘a fag’-and whole cheap
>   cigarettes are also often called fags.
> - 1908 Church Times 7 Feb. 173/1
>   ― He gathered into a leather pouch the remains of his cigarettes, and
>   left the room. ‘What does he do with all those fags?’ asked Conway.
>   1921 Galsworthy To Let iii. viii. 284 ― The fag of Fleur’s
>   cigarette··fell on the grass.
> - 1922 Joyce Ulysses 70 ― Smoking a chewed
>   fagbutt. 1928 Galsworthy Swan Song iv. 24 ― Cinemas, fags, and
>   football matches-there would be no real revolution while they were on
>   hand.
> - 1942 C. Barrett On Wallaby v. 97 ― Cobbers of the men in
>   detention had hit upon an ingenious method of smuggling fags to them.
> - 1945 L. Shelly Jive Talk Dict. 24/1 ― Fag hag, girl chain smoker.
> - 1959 W. Golding Free Fall ii. 49 ― There was the business of the fagcards.
>   We all collected them.

*Fag-end* itself, always according to the OED, comes from an usage of *fag*, meaning "something that hangs loose". I read all this as suggesting that the word for cigarette came about because of the way cigarettes often
hang from smokers' mouths. For a famous example, see Lucky Luke:

[image: Lucky Luke]

Answer (score 2):

**Without any evidence**, the origin of fag may be "fag end", that is the untwisted end of a rope.

[image]
 -

*Surprisingly, the origin of the equivalent French colloquial word, "une clope", is also unknown. Is it the same in German for "kippe"* ?

Comment: Evidence or no  evidence, it looks like a [rolled up ciggie](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rolled+up+ciggy&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVseL3ubnJAhVFyRQKHZ9-B98QsAQIJQ&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=roll+up+ciggie&imgrc=iHTtUpoeNknIcM%3A) though,

Comment: We *do* use the term "fag end" to indicate the dregs of a cigarette. In most cases just the filter and a small remaining section of tobacco. That could just be converging usage rather than derived usage though. not sure.

Comment: There are **fag** ends all over the floor.

Answer (score -5):

I was told in the the ration pack once apon a time you would get packets of cigarettes, they weren't very big 5 or 10 cigereetes per pack and couple dozen matches. It was written on the packet. For "A Good Smoke" or for short, FAGS  .

Comment: This does not answer the question and contains no references to support it. Please edit it, appropriate to the question.

Comment: Acronyms as the foundation for historical words are almost always fake. Please do research before posting here.