# Does the word fascist share a root with the anti-gay slur f****t?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language

My understanding is that the word fascism comes from fasces meaning a bundle of sticks and the slur also had the meaning of a bundle of sticks. Are we looking at false friends?

Comment: [maybe, maybe not](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/377336/77227), apparently

Comment: Yes, they are cognate: [fascist](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fascist), [faggot](https://www.etymonline.com/word/faggot). But also cognate to [fascia](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fascia) (multiple meanings), and [fajita](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fajita).

Comment: Related: [When did “fag” become an offensive word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16130/when-did-fag-become-an-offensive-word) and [Origin of fag (meaning a cigarette in British English)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290786/origin-of-fag-meaning-a-cigarette-in-british-english)

Answer (score 5):

Both terms refer to a bundle of sticks, but in the case of fascist it refers to the Ancient Roman usage as a symbol of power, while in the case of faggots it appears to refer to a worthless bundle, originally used as a derogatory term to refer to a woman. Other suggested origins don’t seem to have any relation to the “fascist” usage:

[Fasces](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fasces?ref=etymonline_crossreference):

> 1590s, from Latin fasces "bundle of rods containing an axe with the blade projecting" (plural of fascis "bundle" of wood, etc.
>
> ***Carried before a lictor, a superior Roman magistrate, as a symbol of power over life and limb: the sticks symbolized punishment by whipping, the axe-head execution by beheading***. Hence in Latin it also meant, figuratively, "high office, supreme power."

Faggot:

> ***The explanation that male homosexuals were called faggots because they were burned at the stake as punishment is an etymological urban legend.***
>
> Burning sometimes was a punishment meted out to homosexuals in Christian Europe (on the suggestion of the Biblical fate of Sodom and Gomorrah), but in ***England, where parliament had made homosexuality a capital offense in 1533, hanging was the method prescribed***.
>
> Use of faggot in connection with public executions had long been obscure English historical trivia by the time the word began to be used for ***"male homosexual" in 20th century American slang, whereas the contemptuous slang word for "woman" (in common with the other possible sources or influences listed here) was in active use early 20c., by D.H. Lawrence and James Joyce, among others.***

(Etymonline)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to have any relation"? You left out entirely the part of the etymonline entry of 'faggot' that established the connection. The two words are derived from the same Latin root word.

Comment: @Mitch -    I mean that though a “bundle of stick” is the original meaning from which both terms derive, fascist refers to the ancient Roman usage, while faggot derive from a very different connotation of bundle of sticks, that is a worthless bundle. Other supposed origin don’t even refer to “bundle of sticks”.

Comment: Sure, the meanings have diverged greatly but there is a direct line of derivation for both back to Latin 'fasces'. The question is 'do they share a root?' and the answer from etymonline is glaringly 'yes'.

Comment: @Mitch - yes, and that’s why the opening line of my answer is “both term refer to a bundle of sticks”. I think it is also worth explaining  that “that bundle”  refers to quite different things, though.

Comment: There's no doubt that the two have diverged in meaning, a strong bundle vs a loose bundle. But the issue us instead if phonetically the different meanings have both a phonetic and semantic common origin. Also, What about the missing paragraph from etymonline?

Comment: @Mitch - there nothing missing.

Comment: right at the start: ["male homosexual," 1914, American English slang, probably from earlier contemptuous term for "woman" (1590s), especially an old and unpleasant one, in reference to faggot (n.1) "bundle of sticks," as something awkward that has to be carried (compare baggage "worthless woman," 1590s). It may also be reinforced by Yiddish faygele "homosexual" (n.), literally "little bird." It also may have roots in British public school slang noun fag "a junior who does certain duties for a senior" (1785), with suggestions of "catamite," ...](https://www.etymonline.com/word/faggot)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to **faggot**, a known decedent of the Latin  **fasces**, a bundle of sticks, there may be another **faggot** in American English that became the  pejorative for male homosexual.

**פֿייגעלע‎ (feygele)** , Yiddish for *little bird* may actually be the source of the pejorative. **Feygele** was used in early 20th Century New York the same way **faggot** is used today.

[Faggot](https://www.etymonline.com/word/faggot) in its current pejorative sense seems to have originated in  early 20th Century America. This would have been the same time period that saw [**feygele**](https://eppylover.livejournal.com/230136.html)  in American Yiddish in the pejorative sense.

There is no point trying to prove that Yiddish slang has contributed to American slang; it has beyond question. And no point trying to prove that **feygele** was the sole origin of the politically incorrect **faggot**. There are endless possibilities here. Among them is that **faggot** was the closest sounding English word to **feygele** some Americans could come up with.

Tracing **faggot** to the German [vogel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vogel) rather than the Latin [fasces](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fasces) would have seemed a stretch to me some years ago. But, I think the origin of this term has not been sufficiently examined. Some uses of (**fasces**) faggot make sense, such as *cigarette*, as they were once sold in bundles. But that faggot in the sense of a male homosexual, does not.

I am prepared to keep my mind open here.

Comment: That is a really interesting take the two words *feygele* and *faggot* certainly reinforce each other.

Comment: The possibly influence of Yiddish 'feygeles' with 'faggot' is noted in the etymonline entry.

Comment: @Mitch 11 .. yes it is, but only a passing reference.  What had me going was the general acceptance that faggot, the pejorative, must come from fasces. I'm not completely convinced. Yiddish had been creeping into American English for a century or so (mostly ending by 1960), not the least because American Yiddish speakers sometimes forgot which language they were speaking. There was a lot of interplay between American English and Yiddish.

Comment: (Only a century? Then it's not Yiddish. *faggot* has "probably" been a derogatory term for ~400y.) > n.2 "male homosexual," 1914, American English slang (shortened form fag is from 1921), probably from earlier contemptuous term for "woman" (1590s), especially an old and unpleasant one, in reference to faggot. – [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/faggot)

Comment: @Mazura... the century would have been about 1860-1960.  The use of faggot for woman is noted, but its general use is not well established.  Many other uses of the word are well established prior to the first quarter of the 20th Century. After that, the term turns sharply to a pejorative for male homosexual in American English.. As I wrote in the answer, my mind is open here, and the question of origin is not really established.

Comment: @Mazura to be fair, "faggot" meaning a woman of sorts was well established in British English, along with a lot of other meanings. As the meaning in question arose in the US,  I got ahead of myself writing my first reply.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's look at the basic etymology of the two words.

*Faggot* etymology:

> Middle English (in the sense ‘bundle of sticks for fuel’): from Old French fagot, from Italian fagotto, based on Greek phakelos ‘bundle’.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/faggot)</sub>

It's important to note that "phakelos" is "φάκελος".

*Fascism* etymology:

> 1920s: from Italian fascismo, from fascio ‘bundle, political group’, from Latin fascis (see fasces).
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fascism)</sub>

According to the [Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages](http://www.bulgari-istoria-2010.com/Rechnici/Etymological%20dictionary%20of%20Lat%20-%20de%20Vaan,%20Michiel_5820.pdf), *fascis* is not related to *phakelos*/*φάκελος*:

> **facis** 'bundle, faggot; (symbol of) power' [m *i*] (Pl.+)
>   IE cognates: Olr. *basc* 'necklace', W. *beich* 'burden', Bret. *bec'h* 'load' < PCl. **b<sup>(h)</sup>askio-*.
>
> An Italo-Celtic correspondence **b<sup>h</sup>aski(o)-* 'bundle' for which no PIE etymology is available. Greek words such as φάκελος 'bundle' and βάσκιοι 'bundles of osiers' (Hsch.) are probably unrelated, since they show irregular alternations within Greek, and do not have exactly the same preform **b<sup>h</sup>aski-(o-)*.

Comment: Excellent online Latin etymology dictionary!